# Expected output from ec2.rebootInstances()?

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the AWS JavaScript SDK (with Node.js) to reboot one of my instances; however, the documentation is unclear about what to expect in the `data` object returned by `ec2.rebootInstances()`.

On [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RebootInstances.html#API_RebootInstances_ResponseElements) it seems to say the `data` object will have a `return` property set to `true` on success, while on [this other page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#rebootInstances-property) it simply says the `data` object will contain "the de-serialized data returned from the request."

In my testing I'm just getting an empty object literal `{}`, and I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.

Here's my very simply code:

```
ec2.rebootInstances({InstanceIds: ['i-abc123']}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Reboot error:', error); // This never gets logged.
    } else {
        console.log('data is:', data); // This always logs "data is: {}"
    }
});
```

Should I assume success, since there is no error, even though the `data` object has no properties?

Answer (score -2):

If I got you question correctly. below will assist.

First given you are using JS all code will run asynchronous and event driven.

So basically when rebootInstances is call is made the response or action can wait for more than 4 mins depending on the situation as highlighted in the documentation below:

[Doc Reference][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aLW6.jpg

Also note that the return object is an **AWS.request object**.

So basically when your code prints out "data" that object has not completed the call back to have values or populated. Best is to follow event driven model based on the return object type, AWS.request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html

Examples and useful events can be found in the above documentation relation to AWS.request, but simple example can be as below (taken from the doc)

[Sample Code][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGPX9.jpg

Comment: None of what you said is relevant because I'm passing a callback to `ec2.rebootInstances()`. Regarding this callback, the documentation says: **Called when a response from the service is returned. If a callback is not supplied, you must call AWS.Request.send() on the returned request object to initiate the request.**